# Data binding using ObservableField of type Spannable

Tags: android, observable, android-databinding

I've been using ObservableField() in my ViewModel. But now I have HTML formatted text that I want to display. Can I use an ObservableField of type Spannable for this? In the old situation I use the method "setEditText" and this works.

**new situation:**

```java
    var spannableText = ObservableField<Spannable>()
    fun setEditTextUsingObservable() {
        var complete = "<ul><li><a href='https://www.someurl.nl/hello/'>Click here!</a></li></ul>"
        this.spannableText.set(complete.toSpannable())
    }
```

**old situation:**

```java
    fun setEditText(textView: TextView, text: String) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            textView.text = Html.fromHtml(text, Html.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE).toSpannable()
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            textView.text = Html.fromHtml(text).toSpannable()
        }
        textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    }
```

The related XML:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>
            <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="MyViewModel" />
        </data>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/spannableText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@{viewModel.spannableText}"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

Comment: isn't that working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is to use a **SpannableString** instead of a Spannable.

```
var spannableText = ObservableField<SpannableString>()

    val text: SpannableString?
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        text = SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(complete, Html.TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE))
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        text = SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(complete))
    }

    spannableText.set(text)
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution is in using bindadapter
**ViewModel**

```java
 val spannable: ObservableField<Spanned> =ObservableField(Html
.fromHtml("<ul><li><a href='https://www.someurl.nl/hello/'>Click here!</a></li></ul>"))


fun changeText(text: String) {
    spannable.set(Html.fromHtml(text))
    }
```

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>
            <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="MyViewModel" />
        </data>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/spannableText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@{viewModel.spannable}"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

**BindAdapter**

```java
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void Spanned(TextView textView, Spanned spannable) {
    textView.setText(spannable);
}
```

now you can use `changeText` function to change it.

Comment: this doesn't compile, ObservableField<Spanned>() cannot be initialized. Is there a more elegant solution than this?

Comment: @JimClermonts try it again I writed ObservableField two times

Comment: Property getter or setter expected. Spanned is an interface is this correct?

Comment: @JimClermonts no you didn't need any setter and getter for this,just try it and it will show your html.why you want setter and getter?for handling links??

Comment: Error: Property getter or setter expected;
Expecting member declaration

Comment: @JimClermonts all right I now what's your mean. ```set``` in ```spannable.set``` is one of ```ObservableField``` method you don't need to declaration it again for each ```ObservableField```

Comment: it doesn't compile.

Comment: No, it doesn't: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required DataBindingComponent is null in class DefaultBindingImpl. A BindingAdapter in  is not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods static.

Comment: @JimClermonts you added bind adapter non static.make it static. ```public static void Spanned(TextView textView, Spanned spannable)```

Comment: this solution is much more code. I've posted the simple solution.